# How to select sub-level entity with Hibernate Criteria Query?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, criteria, hibernate-criteria

Let's say I have this named HQL (findRoomQuery):

```
select r from House h inner join h.roomList r
where h.address = :address and r.roomNo = :roomNo
```

The mapping of House entity is like this:

```
<class name="com.example.House" table="house">      
    <id name="id" column="id" type="long">
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>

    <property name="address" column="address" type="string" length="100" not-null="false"/>
    <set name="roomList" cascade="none" lazy="false" fetch="join" inverse="true"> 
        <key>
            <column name="house_id"/>
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="com.example.Room"/>
    </set>
</class>
```

While the Room entity is like this:

```
<class name="com.example.Room" table="room">        
    <id name="id" column="id" type="long">
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>

    <property name="houseId" column="house_id" type="long" not-null="true"/>
    <property name="roomNo" column="room_no" type="string" length="4" not-null="false"/>
</class>
```

The relationship is a **House** can has one or many **Room**.

The code to execute the query is like this:

```
Query query = getSession().createQuery("findRoomQuery")
                .setParameter("address", address)
                .setParameter("roomNo", roomNo);
return query.list();
```

You can see the HQL return **Room** entities from **select r** (r is alias of h.roomList).

How to do the same thing with Hibernate Criteria Query?
Is it possible?

Comment: Is this correct? "The relationship is a House can has one or many Room." VS "return (Room) query.uniqueResult()";

Comment: @ByteCode: sorry, that's typo, I mean query.list().

Comment: You are searching the room based on room id so I think criteria.uniqueResult(); is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try  this one

```
 Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(House.class, "house"); 
              criteria.createAlias("house.roomList", "roomList");           
              criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("house.address",address));              
              criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("roomList.roomNo", roomNo)); 
              criteria.setProjection(Projections.property("roomList"));

           Room  r =  (Room) criteria.uniqueResult();
```

replace

```
 <property name="houseId" column="house_id" type="long" not-null="true"/>
```

to

```
 <many-to-one name="houseId" class="com.example.House" fetch="select">
            <column name="house_id" not-null="true" />
 </many-to-one>
```

Comment: I got this error: "could not resolve property: roomList of: com.example.House"

Comment: Are you sure house class contain property Set<Room> roomList and its setter and getter

Comment: @suud I just replaced the query to criteria  select r from House h inner join h.roomList r
where h.address = :address and r.roomNo = :roomNo

Comment: ok, at first I applied your code without ";" for each line, I concated them using ".". But now after separated them using ";" I got "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long". It's really weird.

Comment: @suud Make sure address should be string and roomNo should be long.

Comment: you're right, the type of roomNo is String. I had wrapped it with Long.valueOf(), but now I got this error again: "could not resolve property: roomList of: com.example.House" :(

Comment: I'm in position of not allowed to modify the mapping.

Comment: Honestly, I didn't follow your code completely. I used "a" as alias of House.class and "b" as alias of "a.roomList", thus I used `Projections.Property("b")`, maybe `Projections.Property()` can't be used for alias. But after followed your alias naming, the code run without error, but the result was wrong. I checked the generated sql, it's really weird that it returns only id field from House:
`select this_.id as y0_ from HOUSE this_ inner join ROOM b1_ on this_.id=b1_.house_id where this_.address=? and b1_.room_no=?`. I'm thinking if there is a bug in hibernate criteria for this situation?

Comment: @suud I think you need to modify hbm.xml too. We are using annotation configuration with these type of criteria and works well.